# Python File not opening file?

Tags: python, exception, text

So I have this code, and I am trying to have it open a file.  However, the exception part of the code always gets executed.

```
def main():
    #Opens up the file
    try:
        fin = open("blah.txt")
        independence = fin.readlines() 
        fin.close()
        independence.strip("'!,.?-") #Gets rid of the punctuation 
        print independence
        #Should the file not exist
    except:
        print 'No, no, file no here'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I checked to see if the file name was spelled correctly, and it was, and the file is in the same directory as the python file, and I've used this code before.  Why is it not working?

Comment: Please fix indentation!

Comment: You could print the exception and find out why! :)

Comment: Like Fredrik says, we can't tell exactly what's being executed in your Python program at the moment as the indentation is a bit out of sorts - could you fix it so it looks like you have in your editor/IDE?

Comment: Using `except:` with no specific exception checked does not give you any confidence that opening the file is what failed.

Comment: First, as Fredrik said: Fix that indentation!. Second, change your except to `except Exception as e:`, then do `print(e)` in the except clause to see what's being raised. Really, you shouldn't be using a base exception though - if you want to check file not found, do `except IOError as e` to just check that

Answer (score 6):

`independence` is a list of strings. You can't call strip on a list.
Try this:

```
def main():
    fin = open('blah.txt', 'r')
    lines = fin.readlines() 
    fin.close()
    for line in lines:
        print line.strip("'!,.?-")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception, e:
        print '>> Fatal error: %s' % e
```

Comment: that is probably the cause of the error; when you at it, use `with open("blah.txt") as fd` instead

Comment: If you hadn't used a bare `except` there, you would have seen the error, since you would have had `AttributeError` rather than `FileError`.